# ASP.NET 4 MVC Web API: Serialization of an interface to XML

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I manage my objects with a IoC-container (autofac). Because of that I only use interfaces instead of objects.

If my web api returns a object of type "Document" the framework can handle json and xml serialization.
I added [DataContract]-Attributes to the Document-class, but in a interface this is no possible.

So if i want to return a object of type IDocument, i get a HTTP-code 500.
ASP.NET 4 MVC Web API is now RC, can the framework still not serialize interface member into xml?
Json serialization is no problem.

Comment: It's still not working in asp.net-mvc-5:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The types exposed on the Web API interfaces must be DTOs - Data Transfer Objects. Also can be called ViewModels.

It is an anti-pattern to expose your Model on the client-agnostic Web API.

If your API is purely for the consumption of the .NET clients, either you can use WCF or you may use [KnownType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.knowntypeattribute.aspx). It should be OK to use them with interface as well.

Comment: I want a rest api for mobile clients. Okay, maybe I have to use pure classes (DTOs) or I can implement a custom formatter for my xml-representation (json works fine with interfaces)

Comment: There must be a way of using interfaces. Otherwise, what would be the purpose of IoC and the DependencyResolver. The Jsonformatter can do it, but if T want to use a object which is derived from a interface i get: The configured formatter 'System.Web.Http.Tracing.Tracers.XmlMediaTypeFormatterTracer' cannot write an object of type 'WhereSelectListIterator`2'. Even if i cast it to the class type.